# How can I remove error data(overshoot or undershoot) from the averaged dataset?

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, filtering

I got 5000 by 25 matrix dataset from the experiment, but there might be some errors due to several experimental conditions. So I used for loop for the filtration of error data comparing with the average dataset.

I made a for loop as

```
def error_data_1(y_data1):
    error_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for j in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25):
        for i in y_data1.index:
              if y_data1.index[i, j] < 2:
                   c = pd.DataFrame(y_data1.index[i]).T
                   y_data1 = y_data1.drop(i, 0)
   return y_data1, error_data
```

so that I could adjust the control point manually as setting 1 or 2.
But It would be much better compared with the average values of each data point.

So I have created an average matrix by summation of all the column components and divided by the number of rows. And I would like to drop the error data which is not in a range of +- 95% of average data.

Is there any way to compare the two different data frame for eliminating the error by ratio?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you repeat the same code snippet twice? Or I am missing some slight difference between them?